# How to invoke tortoisemerge through a batch script?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, tortoisemerge

**Scenario**:
When I try to reintegrate (merge) the branch to trunk, I want to run some script before the actual merge starts.

Its something like, The moment I click on merge, enter the url & click ok, the script must be run first. This script will run some analysis, based on the result of this analysis, merge continues or aborts.

Can someone guide me on this?

Comment: Merge is a local operation, it only affects your working copy. If you want to run some verification, add this to your build script. You should be running your build (including tests) after merge and before commit anyway.

Comment: I am not using any build scripts. So, can you guide me on, where to add this & how?

Comment: What language are you using? What environment (Visual studio, eclipse)? How much effort should be put into this also depends on the complexity of the project and on how you intend to distribute it.

Comment: I have both sorts of projects. I am using Tortoise SVN which uses TortoiseMerge tool. I want to run this tool only if certain criteria is met (For eg: If %ERRORLEVEL% is 0, only then the merge tool should continue, else must be aborted)

Answer (score 0):

Tsvn `Settings` - `Diff Viewer` - `Merge tool`

Select your *custom* tool (bat-file, which include you tool and conditional run of TortoiseMerge) instead of default selection

Comment: I already tried this. I create a .exe app & set this as custom tool. However, the merge happens using default tool.

Comment: @user3214720 - try also mirror your choice in pure Subversion config: `merge-tool-cmd = merge_command` in [helpers] section